# Writing this line in a natural way

Tags: phrase-request

Recently I have been trying to file a complaint where I need to include the following:

(All texts in the following blockquote are red-colored)

> *Click next after 15 secs*
>
> *Click next after 14 secs*
>
> *Click next after 13 secs*
>
> ⋮
>
> *Click next after 1 secs*

The line flashing on the screen keeps changing every passing second like given above.

I tried to describe that in the email:

> I notice that while we are on the page where we have to enter the
>   names of the passengers, it flashes 'Click Next after xx secs' in red
>   with a clock attached with the text where xx goes from 15 -> 0

That is pretty awkward and not very clear and visual. What would be the best way to write the same?

Comment: Welcome to our community! To keep the quality of the questions high, we do not answer proofreading requests. Unfortunately, the way your question is currently formulated, raises the alarms of being such question. To make it on-topic, you need to tell us what confuses you. For more info, please see [Alternative websites for proofreading](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/263/) and [Details, please!](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/).

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. I am not asking you to proofread it. I am asking you how do I go about saying the same thing. Normally, we are asked to show some effort about what we have tried and why we do not think our wording is not applicable. If you notice carefully, I have written in my last line that the way I have written is pretty awkward and doesn't seem like a natural way a native speaker would speak about it.

Comment: Well, you're looking for writing advice *and* proofreading and that's the difference. Writing advice is off-topic too.

Comment: That's also off-topic. I don't see your point there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On the passenger name entry screen, there is a 15 second countdown flashing in red "Click Next after ** secs".

Answer (score 4):

This is a tricky bug to describe in a single sentence. Try using multiple sentences.

For example:

> There is a bug on the page where we have to enter the names of the
>   passengers. It flashes 'Click next after x secs' in red. 'X' counts
>   down from 15 to 0.

Comment: General tips for reporting bugs (I'm a software tester):

Comment: Explain why this bug is a problem (is it annoying? does the page time out after 15 seconds?), what causes it to happen (is it every time you're entering names?), and what software you're using (Chrome? Firefox? Windows? Mac? Which version?)

Comment: It's not about the bug. I have described it pretty well. I just need to know how do I write the count down thing in a clear fashion.

Comment: +1 for "try using multiple sentences" and the clear example of that approach.

Answer (score 1):

> On the page where we enter the names of passengers, a red-text alert
>   flashes "Click next after X secs" every second, from 15 down to one.

Answer (score 1):

On the screen where we enter passenger names, there flashes a warning in red text: "Click next after 15 secs" where the number of remaining seconds counts down each second to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

> When I have to enter the names of passengers, there is some flashing red text that reads "Click next after 15 secs" - which is updated every second counting down from fifteen seconds to one second.

Where fifteen is 15 and one is 1.

This is the best way to write it in my opinion.